# How to find the ID of a specific field in Qualtrics without previewing?

Tags: qualtrics

I'm working on a survey in Qualtrics, and am needing to make certain fields readonly (I'm currently doing this via `$j("#QR\\~QID186\\#1\\~14\\~1\\~TEXT").attr("readonly", true);` for any IDs I know).

I'm currently getting certain IDs by previewing the survey in my browser and inspecting the element - no problem (as pointed out [in their documentation](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/developer-tools/custom-programming/survey-javascript-methods/#AnswerChoices)).  This is working for most fields, except ones with a lot of display logic on them.  The display logic is taking into account previous answers and doing calculations on them - it's a little obfuscated as I don't know the content of the survey that well.  So for these fields, it's incredibly tedious just to get the field to display in the first place by manipulating my input data.

It doesn't explain if it's even possible in their documentation, so it may be a long shot, but is there actually a way for me to get the ID of an element if I'm only in the "Edit Survey" section of Qualtrics, without having to preview it?

Comment: The only way to see the QID from "Edit Survey" is to change the question, then move to another question.  When the question is saved the QID will briefly show on the top left under "Saving".  However, when using javascript it is usually just best to let Qualtrics get the QID for you: var qid = this.questionId;

Comment: That's alright for finding the QID (Traci's answer covers this now), but I'm actually looking for specific field IDs.  The best option I've been given by Qualtrics so far is to duplicate the survey and remove all display logic.  That way you're able to preview the questions and their fields without having to deal with the logic around them.

Comment: You might be able to get the choices you are looking for programmatically through javascript. Look at https://ut1.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/QuestionAPI/classes/Qualtrics JavaScript Question API.html (copy and paste the url since StackOverflow link doesn't get the whole thing due to spaces). The QuestionInfo object has info about all the choices and there are some methods to search for choices with certain attributes.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones did you ever get this figured out? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the top right corner of the Qualtrics screen where you have your name, the drop down from that allows you to look at account settings. Once in this menu, you can select "Qualtrics IDs" in the Grey Ribbon. From there select the survey you want to examine and a separate window will pop up with all the Question IDs associated with that survey.

Comment: Though this is helpful for Question IDs, I'm actually looking for individual field IDs - for instance, the textbox itself, not the question.